# Unable to open Ubuntu software center, Synaptic manager or install updates

Tags: installation, package-management

I cannot open Ubuntu Software Center, Synaptic Package Manager or install any updates.
Below is what I get;

```
An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right -click 
menu or apt get in a terminal to see what wrong. The error message was
' Unknown Error: '<type ' exceptions . System Error '> CE: The package
language – pack – kde – en- base- needs to be reinstalled, but I can't
find  an archive for it)' This usually means that you installed
packages have unmet dependencies.
```

How can I get it fixed? How am I suppose to do this using terminal?

Comment: Open a terminal and enter `sudo apt-get install -f`  enter your password.  Edit your question to include the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get purge packagename` --> Where packagename is the application you've installed. This should remove the application.

Then, try `sudo apt-get autoremove` --> This should remove all the unused dependencies.

Finally, try `sudo apt-get install packagename` --> Installs the required package.

Hope that helps. :)